# GWT: Setting specific styles for Cell in Cell Browser

Tags: css, gwt, cellbrowser

I need to set up specific styles of Cell Browser cells in GWT from a CSS file. Any pointers on how to do it

Answer (score 1):

*If you are using 2.4 or 2.5 sdk of GWT*

Override `getCellStyleNames()` while creating column.

```
            TextColumn<String> col= new TextColumn<String>() {

                @Override
               public String getCellStyleNames(Context context, String  object) {
                     return "yourStylee";
                 }  

                @Override
                public String  getValue(String object) {                                            
                return object.getName();
                }           

              };

        };
```

If its cell

```
    public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, Meeting object, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {

        sb.append(SafeHtmlUtils.fromString(" <div class=youclass><table>"));
        // Code goes here
        sb.append(SafeHtmlUtils.fromString("<table> </div>"));
```

Comment: I am using GWT 2.5 but not creating any columns. I am currently working on GWT showcase project.

Comment: Otherwise while creating cell itself you can ovveride the render method,In that you can add your class.

Comment: Sorry cannot post code. But lets take it to be GWT showcase at http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellBrowser

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the css style on any widget using methods from UIObject. In this case something like this should work:

```
cellBrowserInstance.setStylePrimaryName("newStyle");
```

with "newStyle" being listed in your CSS.